# Executing Jenkins job on multiple environments

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, environment-variables, postman

I have a parameterized Jenkins job using Choice Parameter(environment) listing multiple environments to choose from such as Test, Pre-Prod, and Production.

Then I have a Windows batch command which by default always choose Test environment to run the job.

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command "& '%WORKSPACE%\Jenkins_PostmanDemo.ps1'" "'%environment%.postman_environment.json'" "%WORKSPACE%"
```

I want to run this same job parallelly every day in different environments. How can I d? it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to have separate jobs for different environments for better customization, for example, preprod can perform the auto deploy part but not for prod.

My company has the exact problem and we have them implemented with different jobs.

However, if you really want to do it with different parameters, I would suggest you use Dynamic Parameter Plugin: 
https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=60916644#content/view/60916644

Comment: Thanks, @Near - I tried using dynamic parameter plugin but couldn't make it work so for now created different job per environment as you suggested.